# How to index star rating in google?

Tags: html, css, seo, google-search-console, google-crawlers

So here is the HTML markup that I have on my site and it displays star rating with the help of some css.

Now I have read this entire [google document](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/172705?hl=en) but I am still not able to understand how to change my markup. I am not willing to make changes in css and I don't have that much data available with me so that can create markup as per microdata/RDF as mentioned in google docs.

What is the minimum change that I can make so that google understands aggregate rating for the item?

```
<div class="store__rating">
   <meta content="5" itemprop="rating">
   <div class="rateStars"><span class="filled_green"><i class="icon-star"></i></span>
      <span class="filled_green"><i class="icon-star"></i></span>
      <span class="filled_green"><i class="icon-star"></i></span>
      <span class="filled_green"><i class="icon-star"></i></span>
      <span class="filled_green"><i class="icon-star"></i></span>
      <span class="reviewCount">
      2Reviews
      </span>
   </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing like this, [here is the testing tool](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/), just paste the HTML and validate

```
<div class="store__rating" typeof="v:Review-aggregate" xmlns:v="http://rdf.data-vocabulary.org/#">
   <span rel="v:rating">
       <span typeof="v:Rating">
         <span content="5" property="v:average"></span>
         <span content="5" property="v:best"></span>
       </span>
   </span>
   <span content="2" property="v:count"></span>
   <div class="rateStars"><span class="filled_green"><i class="icon-star"></i></span>
      <span class="filled_green"><i class="icon-star"></i></span>
      <span class="filled_green"><i class="icon-star"></i></span>
      <span class="filled_green"><i class="icon-star"></i></span>
      <span class="filled_green"><i class="icon-star"></i></span>
      <span class="reviewCount">
      2 Reviews
      </span>
   </div>
</div>
```